# IIS return error 500 when sending files via php curl but not via postman

Tags: php, curl, iis

this is my scenario. a web application written in PHP (7.x) that a certain point sends some informations and 2 files to a web server via cURL. The web server have some Rest APIs also written in PHP (7.x).

my problem is that when I send the files, IIS (7.5) on the server (Win 2008 R2) return an "500 internal server error". Looking to error details the error code is "0x80070026"

If I deploy the API on another server with Apache the API runs fine.
On IIS I've done some tests and:
- If I send the cURL command without the files the API runs fine.
- If I call the API with Postman and with files attached the API runs fine too.

web app have this code

```
$url = $this->config->item('API_endpoint').'Scans/scans/';
        $username = $this->config->item('API_username');
        $password = $this->config->item('API_password');
        //$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');

        $postData = array(
            'scanDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ...other data...
            'file1' => curl_file_create('file1.stl'),
            'file2' => curl_file_create('file2.stl')
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

        $result=curl_exec($ch);
```

The script on the server read the data and save the files.

I tried also to add 
`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');`

IIS logs show

> 2020-06-09 10:37:27 172.31.2.11 POST /index.php/Scans/scans/ - yyyy - x.x.x.x Mozilla/4.0+(Compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0) **500 0 38** 405

thanks!

---

edit:
in my curl script I've added a var_dump($result);

[this is the output, with "detailed" error of IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxCIk.jpg)

Comment: You should print out the actual error page which should tell what's up. Or use tools like Wireshark to capture such from packets.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output on my post

Comment: So IIS thinks the error 500.0 came from the PHP application. Not sure why, but can you capture and compare the packets sent by curl and postman? The differences in them can explain the error.

Comment: honestly I don't know how to do that. I tried with Wireshark but the output it gives to me is too messy. IIS logs for Postman request is this: 2020-06-09 09:23:33 172.31.2.11 POST /index.php/Scans/scans/ - yyyy - x.x.x.x PostmanRuntime/7.25.0 200 0 0 124

Comment: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/HTTP Check HTTP request/response is probably one of the simplest tasks to do in Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. The difference seems to be in the content length header. when sending via Postman or via browser without the file attached the content length seems legit, with the file attached the content length is like 60Byte. I tried to change my code to be sure the file path is correct with "file" => curl_file_create('C:/MAMP/htdocs/APP_NAME/assets/file.stl') but I still get the strange content length

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PHP 7.3 on IIS, with wireshark I found that CURL sends *100-continue* requests just after the original *POST* request, POSTMAN does not.

I added the option
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));`
To my curl request to aviod it

This made CURL to stop sending *100-continue* and IIS does not throw *500* with error code *x80070026* any more.